# CreateJS hittest between a stage object and a container child?

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, createjs, hittest

I have a side scrolling game, so instead of moving the character, you have the character centered and everything else movies past him.

The character sprite is added directly to the stage, but the background image + a tree sprite is added to a container and the container is added to the stage.

I want to do a hit test between the character and the tree. The problem is that the tree x and y coordinates do not change because it's attached to the container, so they never overlap with the character's coordinates, thus no collision.

How do you do a hit test between a stage object and a container object?

Or am I doing it wrong and I should add the tree as a stage object and move it separately to the container?

Comment: are you able to iterate over the entities in the container? Sounds like you need a way to translate container coordinate space to player coordinate space.

Comment: have a look at localToGlobal. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_localToGlobal